# Dynamically spawning camel routes after consuming a .properties file

Tags: apache-camel

I've written a basic route builder that pulls a file a from a location, does some message transformations, and then sends it somewhere else. The start and endpoints I currently have set in a .properties file.

The goal of my project is to be able to have a static camel route that consumes .properties file and creates the routes from the route builder that I've already written with the start and endpoints being specified in the properties file. How would I go about doing something like this? Am I approaching the problem incorrectly?

Thanks in advance guys!

EDIT with more explaination:

So currently my camel routes look something like this:

{{fileInput}} -> camel routes -> {{fileOutputs}}

I have a .properties file that specifies a single input endpoint and a single output endpoint. However, I would like my end code to be something like this:

{{fileInput1}} -> camel routes -> {{fileOutputs1}}

{{fileInput2}} -> camel routes -> {{fileOutputs2}}

{{fileInput3}} -> camel routes -> {{fileOutputs3}}

.
.
.

{{fileInputN}} -> camel routes -> {{fileOutputsN}}

My original idea was to have a separate static camel route that polls a specific file location. If I needed a new route I would just drop a .properties file in there and the route would consume the .properties file and generate one of the above routes. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You don't mention whether you're using spring, but if you are then you can use spring properties in your camel routes in a more direct way: (http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html) and (http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html) may be of interest.

Comment: You might also be able to leverage the [dynamic router EIP](https://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html) and/or the [routing slip EIP](https://camel.apache.org/routing-slip.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load the property file inside your RouteBuilder.

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(input);
```

Then use them.

```
prop.getProperty("MySuperProperty");
```

Yet I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think I explained this properly (partly because I'm still struggling with the problem definition myself). I edited my question to explain this more adequately.